# How can I access request in Play Guice Module?

Tags: playframework, request, guice

I am writing an application which handles multiple systems. The user can choose the system which he wants to work with and I store that system ID in session (client session)

Now I have Service classes, lets say CustomerService.

```
class CustomerService(val systemID: String) {
    // Implementation
}
```

I want to use Guice to inject the Customer instance to the Controllers. But I want to instantiate the CustomerService with SystemID which is stored in the session.

How can I access `request.session` in Guice Module?

**Edit:**

Had simplified my code above. My actual code uses interfaces. How can I use assisted inject for this?

```
trait CustomerService(val systemID: String) {
    // Definition
}

object CustomerService{

  trait Factory {
    def apply(systemID: String) : CustomerService
  }

}

class DefaultCustomerService @Inject() (@Assisted systemID: String)
  extends CustomerService {
    // Definition
}

class CustomerController @Inject()(
                            val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
                            csFactory: CustomerService.Factory)
{
}
```

This gives me:
CustomerService is an interface, not a concrete class.  Unable to create AssistedInject factory.

And I do not want to put the Factory under `DefaultCustomerService` and use `DefaultCustomerService.Factory` in the controller. This is because for unit testing I will be using `TestCustomerService` stub and want Dependency Injection to inject `TestCustomerService` into the controller instead of `DefaultCustomerService`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not do that. If you need to inject an instance of something that requires runtime-values, you can use guice's [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

Here's how you can use it with play:

1. Create a factory of your service with the runtime value as parameter:

```
object CustomerService {
  trait Factory {
    def apply(val systemID: String): CustomerService
  }
}
```

2. Implement your service with the assisted parameter

```
class CustomerService @Inject() (@Assisted systemId: String) { .. }
```

3. Bind the factory in your guice module:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
  .implement(classOf[CustomerService], classOf[CustomerServiceImpl])
  .build(classOf[CustomerService.Factory]))
```

4. And finally inject the factory where you need the customer service:

```
class MyController @Inject() (csFactory: CustomerService.Factory) { .. }
```

Here's another example of assisted inject:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients

Comment: Thanks rethab - but please see my edit in the question.

Comment: FactoryModuleBuilder has a method 'implement', in which you can bind a trait to a class. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks I found it! If you can add that to your answer I will accept it.