# ProvisionException: Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

I am using Guice in PlayFramework but I am getting runtime error:

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.DirectUserController. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at controllers.DirectUserController.class(DirectUserController.scala:90)
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider<controllers.DirectUserController>
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:124)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:111) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
```

Here is the code:

```
trait FactoryHandlerTrait {
  def getDirectUserFactory: DirectUserFactory

  def getUserRepository: UserRepository

  def getUrlRepository: URLRepository
}

class FactoryHandler(var s: String = "real") extends FactoryHandlerTrait {
  def getDirectUserFactory: DirectUserFactory = {
    //implementation here
  }

  def getUserRepository: UserRepository = {
    //implementation here
  }

  def getUrlRepository: URLRepository = {
    //implementation here
  }
}

class DependencyModule extends Module {

  def configure(binder: Binder) = {
    binder.bind(classOf[FactoryHandlerTrait]).to(classOf[FactoryHandler])
  }
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
class DirectUserController(var factory:FactoryHandlerTrait) extends Controller {  
  //rest of the code
}
```

In `build.sbt` I have added:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? How to avoid that exception?

I am using Play 2.4.3 and Guice 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

As guice says, either the constructor must have zero arguments or you need to annotate it with `@Inject`. Neither of these requirements is satisfied for your class `FactoryHandler`.

When resolving this, you might want to think about whether the parameter `s` is actually an argument that could be injected by guice (probably not). Therefore, you need to pass that in somehow else. If it's only available at runtime, you might want to take a look at assisted inject. I have described how this works in a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960962/1080523